# Sort dict by sub-value in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I spent some time reading on SOF and am having issues solving this problem.  I cannot seem to find how to get the following data structure sorted by the sub-value:

```
data = {}
data[1] = {name: "Bob", ...}
data[2] = {name: "Carl", ...}
data[3] = {nane: "Alice", ...}
```

I need to get this data into some form of a list/tuple/order dict structure which is alphabetized so that the final result is something like this:

```
finalData = [{name: "Alice", ...}, {name: "Bob", ...}, {name: "Carl", ...}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're mixing and matching your container types.  A `list` uses numerical indices and is ordered / can be sorted.  A `dict` is a key-value store which is inherently unordered.  You can generate a sorted representation of the data in a `dict`, but the `dict` itself will remain unsorted.  You could also look into `OrderedDict`.

Comment: If you had a list of these dictionaries (which seems to make more sense), you'd need something like `data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter("name"))`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Sort a dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
sorted(data.values(), key=itemgetter(name))
```

---

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> data = {}
>>> name = 'name'
>>> 
>>> data[1] = {name: "Bob"}
>>> data[2] = {name: "Carl"}
>>> data[3] = {name: "Alice"}
>>>
>>> sorted(data.values(), key=itemgetter(name))
[{'name': 'Alice'}, {'name': 'Bob'}, {'name': 'Carl'}]
```

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I needed.  Thanks for the help, been stuck on this for a day.