# Python: Sorting an array based on a subvalue

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following data structure:

```
[ 
    { some: thing9,
      key: 9,
    },
     { some: thing3,
      key: 3,
    },
    { some: thing2,
      key: 2,
    },
    { some: thing1,
      key: 1,
    }
]
```

How can I sort this array based on the key value of the dictionary so I get:

```
[ 
    { some: thing1,
      key: 1,
    },
     { some: thing2,
      key: 2,
    },
    { some: thing3,
      key: 3,
    },
    { some: thing9,
      key: 9,
    }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: And [Sort dict by sub-value in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384570/sort-dict-by-sub-value-in-python?rq=1), and various other dups. Although most of them are about sorting a `dict`'s items rather than sorting a `list`, basically the same answer applies without the `.items()` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter('key'))
```

The [Sorting HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) explains this in more detail. But the basic idea is that all sort-related functions take a `key` argument, a callable that's applied to each value before comparing the values.

So, we want `key` to take one of the elements of your `list`, and return the thing you want to sort by. The elements are `dict`s, and you want to sort by their `key` item. The [`itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) function does exactly what you want. (If that function weren't available, you could use, e.g., `lambda item: item['key']` instead.)

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to use lambda expressions, this is also an suitable way of solving your problem:

```
sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['key'])
```

So:

```
from pprint import pprint

data = [
    { 'some': 'thing9',
      'key': 9,
    },
    { 'some': 'thing3',
      'key': 3,
    },
    { 'some': 'thing2',
      'key': 2,
    },
    { 'some': 'thing1',
      'key': 1,
    }
]

pprint(sorted(data, key=lambda x:x['key']))
```

outputs

```
[{'key': 1, 'some': 'thing1'},
 {'key': 2, 'some': 'thing2'},
 {'key': 3, 'some': 'thing3'},
 {'key': 9, 'some': 'thing9'}]
```